# Channel has a strange behaviorior, why block?

Tags: go

go version go1.11.4 darwin/amd64

A new channel and goroutine were created, and the content of the old channel was transferred to the new channel through goroutine. It should not block, but after testing, it was found to be blocked.

thanks.

```golang
type waiter struct {
    ch1   chan struct{}
    ch2   <-chan time.Time
    limit int
    count int
}

func (w *waiter) recv1Block() chan struct{} {
    ch := make(chan struct{})
    go func() {
        for m := range w.ch1 {
            ch <- m
        }
    }()
    return ch
}

func (w *waiter) runBlock(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()

    i := 0
    for i < w.limit {
        select {
        case <-w.recv1Block():  **// why block here?**
            i++
        case <-w.recv2():
        }
    }
    w.count = i
}
```

why `recv1Block` will be block.

Comment: The select will block if nothing sends to `w.ch1` or the channel returned by `w.recv2()`. Show a complete example including the code for `recv2`.

Comment: ok. the code is long which can't be post in comment. read the link https://gist.github.com/johncming/015106bc919d12110e81ca3f2fdf2358. there are two test cases, the second will be block which I don't know why. thanks for you reply.

Comment: It is a large amount of code to understand. Please create a [minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example illustrating the problem.

Comment: Furthrrmore, I would like to point out that you can edit your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Every time* you call `recv1Block()`, it creates a new channel and launches a background goroutine that tries to read all of the data from it.  Since you're calling it in a loop, you will have many things all trying to consume the data from the channel; since the channel never closes, all of the goroutines will run forever.

As an exercise, you might try changing your code to pass around a `chan int` instead of a `chan struct{}`, and write a series of sequential numbers, and print them out as they're ultimately received.  A sequence like this is valid:

1. `run` on goroutine #1 calls `recv1Block()`.
2. `recv1Block()` on GR#1 spawns GR#2, and returns channel#2.
3. `run` on GR#1 blocks receiving on channel#2.
4. `recv1Block()` on GR#2 reads `0` from `w.c1`.
5. `recv1Block()` on GR#2 writes `0` to channel#2 (where `run` on GR#1 is ready to read).
6. `recv1Block()` on GR#2 reads `1` from `w.c1`.
7. `recv1Block()` on GR#2 wants to write `0` to channel#2 but blocks.
8. `run` on GR#1 wakes up, and receives the `0`.
9. `run` on GR#1 calls `recv1Block()`.
10. `recv1Block()` on GR#1 spawns GR#3, and returns channel #3.
11. `recv1Block()` on GR#3 reads `2` from `w.c1`.
12. ...

Notice that the value 1 in this sequence will never be written anywhere, and in fact there is nothing left that could read it.

The easy solution here is to not call the channel-creating function in a loop:

```
func (w *waiter) runBlock(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    ch1 := w.recv1Block()
    ch2 := w.recv2()
    for {
        select {
        case _, ok := <-ch1:
            if !ok {
                return
            }
            w.count++
        case <-ch2:
    }
}
```

It's also standard practice to close channels when you're done with them.  This will terminate a `for ... range ch` loop, and it will appear as readable to a `select` statement.  In your top-level generator function:

```
for i := 0; i < w.limit; i++ {
    w.ch1 <- struct{}{}
}
close(w.ch1)
```

And in your "copy the channel" function:

```
func (w *waiter) recv1Block() chan struct{} {
    ch := make(chan struct{})
    go func() {
        for m := range w.ch1 {
            ch <- m
        }
        close(ch)
    }()
    return ch
}
```

This also means that you don't need to run the main loop by "dead reckoning", expecting it to produce exactly 100 items then stop; you can stop whenever its channel exits.  The consumer loop I show above does this.